# Set different seed in loop causing warnings in R

Tags: r

In R package I want to draw numbers from Nnorm distribution with different seed. I've done it in loop. Seed is set by each value of vector of 310 observations. Unfortunatelly I got warnings like: "number of posisionts of replacing is not multiple of....". When I set constant seed it works.

CODE:

```
mojaCharyzma = 2 * (3 + 6 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 8)
seed = dane$id_student

leader = matrix(0,310,1)

for(i in (1:310))
{
  set.seed(seed[i])
  leader[i,1] = rnorm(n = nrow(dane), mean = mojaCharyzma, sd = 7)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this. Your matrix only has a single column so why not do

```
leader <- matrix(rnorm(n = nrow(dane), mean = mojaCharyzma, sd = 7), ncol=1)
```

Comment: Constantly resetting your random seed is a bad idea. It can ruin the distribution you are hoping for. Is there a particular reason you are resetting the seed each time?

Comment: I need to set it each time from 1:310. It's exercise and I have to do this in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
n = nrow(dane)
```

I suppose that nrow(dane) is > 1? If for example nrow(dane) is 10, then rnorm() will return 10 values. You however want to put all **ten** values into **one** single matrix cell called `leader[i,1]`. Thats of course not possible. 
Change it to

```
n = 1
```

otherwise this matrix assignment wont work.

Note: The seed should have no influence on the problem.